# R-Find missing values from the dataframe and insert value in that position

Tags: r

Using R script I read values from database. The values  contains the following data frame.

```
>values #return the output as follows

ID           Date      Hour      Value
1          2013-06-01    8           9
2          2013-06-01    9          17
3          2013-06-01   10          16
4          2013-06-01   11          21
5          2013-06-01   12          19
6          2013-06-01   13          15
7          2013-06-01   14          14
8          2013-06-01   15          14
9          2013-06-01   16          21
10         2013-06-01   17          22
11         2013-06-01   18          13
12         2013-06-01   19           2
13         2013-06-01   20           2
14         2013-06-01   21           1
15         2013-06-01   22           1
16         2013-06-01   23           1
17         2013-06-02    0           0
18         2013-06-02    1           0
19         2013-06-02    2           0
20         2013-06-02    3           1
21         2013-06-02    4           0
22         2013-06-02    5           0
23         2013-06-02    6           1
24         2013-06-02    7           1
25         2013-06-02    8          20
26         2013-06-02    9          21
27         2013-06-02   10          21
28         2013-06-02   11          15
29         2013-06-02   12          12
30         2013-06-02   13          11
31         2013-06-02   14          10
32         2013-06-02   15          16
33         2013-06-02   16          21
34         2013-06-02   17          22
35         2013-06-02   18          18
36         2013-06-02   19           9
37         2013-06-02   20           2
38         2013-06-02   21           0
39         2013-06-02   23           0
```

I want to find out the missing hours in the dataframe and add  0 to the Value in that missing hour of the date.
 Example:
 From the above dataframe **values**,
 the hour 22 is missing for the date 2013-06-02. I want to insert  a row between the hour 21 and 23 as

```
ID           Date      Hour      Value
39         2013-06-02    22         0
```

How can i achieve this?

I tried as follows:

I have a hours list as

```
>hours<-c(0:23)
> hours #return as follows
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23

>i<-values$Hour[1]+1
>count<-nrow(values)
>for(j in 1:count){
+h<-values$Hour[j]
+hr<-hours[i]
+if(h != hr)
+{
+#write code to insert row
+}
+i<-i+1
+if(i==25)
+{
+i<-c(1)
+}
+}
```

Please help me...

Comment: What would you want the `id` to be for `Date = 2013-06-01` the first 7 entries... that is, Hour = 0:7...?

Comment: Then, shouldn't `ID` value for `Date=2013-06-02, Hour=22` be `NA` as well (instead of 39 as you've shown)?

Comment: @Arun I want to insert like this format.

Comment: You mean you don't want to fill missing hours for 2013-06-01? I don't understand...

Comment: yes. I mentioned an example above- date=2013-06-02,hour=22. The ID is varying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each date make rows 0:23, convert to dataframe, then merge with your data.

Your data:

```
values <- read.table(text="ID           Date      Hour      Value
1          2013-06-01    8           9
2          2013-06-01    9          17
3          2013-06-01   10          16
4          2013-06-01   11          21
5          2013-06-01   12          19
6          2013-06-01   13          15
7          2013-06-01   14          14
8          2013-06-01   15          14
9          2013-06-01   16          21
10         2013-06-01   17          22
11         2013-06-01   18          13
12         2013-06-01   19           2
13         2013-06-01   20           2
14         2013-06-01   21           1
15         2013-06-01   22           1
16         2013-06-01   23           1
17         2013-06-02    0           0
18         2013-06-02    1           0
19         2013-06-02    2           0
20         2013-06-02    3           1
21         2013-06-02    4           0
22         2013-06-02    5           0
23         2013-06-02    6           1
24         2013-06-02    7           1
25         2013-06-02    8          20
26         2013-06-02    9          21
27         2013-06-02   10          21
28         2013-06-02   11          15
29         2013-06-02   12          12
30         2013-06-02   13          11
31         2013-06-02   14          10
32         2013-06-02   15          16
33         2013-06-02   16          21
34         2013-06-02   17          22
35         2013-06-02   18          18
36         2013-06-02   19           9
37         2013-06-02   20           2
38         2013-06-02   21           0
39         2013-06-02   23           0", header = TRUE, as.is=T)
```

Here's the code:

```
#make dummy data frame with all dates and hours
dummy <- as.data.frame(
  cbind(
    sort(rep(unique(values$Date),24)),
    rep(0:23,length(unique(values$Date)))))
colnames(dummy) <- c("Date","Hour")
dummy$Date <- as.character(dummy$Date)
dummy$Hour <- as.numeric(as.character(dummy$Hour))

#merge with values dataframe
values_v1 <- merge(dummy,values,all.x=T)

#substitute NAs with 0(zero)
values_v1[is.na(values_v1)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table) 
# install the package and then load if you don't have it already
dt <- data.table(values, key="Hour")
out <- merge(dt[, .SD[J(Hour[1]:23), roll=-Inf], by=Date, 
      .SDcols = c("Hour", "ID")], dt[, list(Date, Hour, Value)], 
      by=c("Date", "Hour"), all=TRUE)[is.na(Value), Value := 0L]
```

---

Explanation: Your problem is a bit different/complicated because 1) you seem to want to fill in missing values only when they happen in the middle but not anywhere else (beginning or end) and 2) you want to fill the missing value of `ID` with the same value of the last non-missing `ID` (which can be accomplished with a `roll`), but you want to fill the `Value` corresponding to the missing `ID` with 0 (which can't be accomplished with a `roll`).

So, the idea then, is to first get just the missing value of `ID` by using `roll=-Inf`. This is accomplished by the statement:

```
dt[, .SD[J(Hour[1]:23), roll=-Inf], by=Date, .SDcols = c("Hour", "ID")]
```

This is after setting the key to `Hour`.

Now, we need to get a `NA` for `Value` for the newly added `ID`. So, we `merge` it back with `dt` (with `ID` removed, as we've already taken care of it). This is done by:

```
dt[, list(Date, Hour, Value)]
```

Once we've these, we `merge` on the columns `Date, Hour` and use the parameter `all=TRUE` to fill in missing values as well. Finally, we replace any `NA` for `Value` to 0.

Comment: I don't really get it (I'll have to play around with it for a bit), but it works, so have a +1 on me. Cool code!

Comment: @SimonO101, Which part of the explanation is unclear to you (so that I can try to explain it better)?

Comment: Well I don't now how `roll=-Inf` works for a start, but it's not your explanation that doesn't make sense, it's my comprehension of the `data.table` package is not yet good enough. It's my problem, not yours!

Comment: Alright. A very easy way to understand it is with an example. Try this and examine the output: `dd <- data.table(x=c(1:4, 6), y=c(6,7,8,9,11), key="x"); dd[J(1:6)]; dd[J(1:6), roll=Inf]; dd[J(1:6), roll=-Inf]` and read `roll` from `?data.table` after having a look at the outputs.

Comment: But when I try to run your code it says `Error: could not find function "data.table"` please help me... :-)

Comment: I get it. One rolls the previous obs into missing values and the other rolls the next observation back into a missing value. :-) Thanks